# Separated S3 access for different users of the app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Given application with teams(or teams inside of company). Each company can have any amount of teams. Each team can have any amount of users.

How do I provide private S3 storage for each group of users of my application? So only team members and managers could see attachments inside current group?

Comment: How will the team members be 'using' Amazon S3? Will they be directly accessing it, or will they be using an app that stores data in S3? You mention "users of my application", so presumably it is actually the application that stores the data in S3, rather than the users doing it directly?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes. The app uses S3, users save file to the S3 through the app.

Answer (score 0):

Since users are accessing Amazon S3 via your application, they should *not* be given any AWS credentials (eg IAM User credentials). Instead, **the application would be responsible for all security of objects in Amazon S3**.

It would work as follows:

- All objects in Amazon S3 are kept **private**
- The credentials used by your application, however, has full access to the objects in S3
- When a user requests access to an object, or an object needs to be referenced within an HTML page (eg `<img>` tag), the application creates an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to a private object
- When the user follows this link, or the browser references the link, **Amazon S3 verifies the pre-signed URL** and grants access to the object. (If, however, the time period has expired, access would be denied.)
- If a user wishes to **upload** a file, then the application can generate a [pre-signed URL for uploads](https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d), which will grant permission to upload an object directly to a private S3 bucket

At all times, your application will be responsible for determining whether a user is permitted to download or upload an object. The application 'signs' the request, and S3 will permit the operation.

As an example, imagine a **photo-sharing application**. The flow would be:

- Users authenticate to the application
- The application shows them thumbnails of their photos (using pre-signed URLs in the `<img>` tags)
- Users choose to *share* photos with other users, which the application records in its database
- When another user requests to see a shared photo, the application checks the sharing information within the database and, if they are permitted to view the photo, generates a pre-signed URL granting temporary access to the photo